# Does LibGit2Sharp support cloning a repository from the local file system?

Tags: c#, libgit2, libgit2sharp

I am trying to clone a git repository from the local file system:

```
using System;
using LibGit2Sharp;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var sourceUrl = @"file:///c:/work/libgit2sharp";
        using (Repository.Clone(sourceUrl, "targetDir", bare: true))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("repository successfully cloned");
        }
    }
}
```

and I get an exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: LibGit2Sharp.LibGit2SharpException: An error was raised by libgit2. Category = Odb (Error).
Failed to find the memory window file to deregister
   at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Ensure.Success(Int32 result, Boolean allowPositiveResult) in c:\work\libgit2sharp\LibGit2Sharp\Core\Ensure.cs:line 85
   at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Proxy.git_clone_bare(String url, String workdir, git_transfer_progress_callback transfer_cb) in c:\work\libgit2sharp\LibGit2Sharp\Core\Proxy.cs:line 219
   at LibGit2Sharp.Repository.Clone(String sourceUrl, String workdirPath, Boolean bare, Boolean checkout, TransferProgressHandler onTransferProgress, CheckoutProgressHandler onCheckoutProgress) in c:\work\libgit2sharp\LibGit2Sharp\Repository.cs:line 431
   at Program.Main() in c:\work\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line 10
```

I've also tried the following source url:

```
var sourceUrl = @"c:\work\libgit2sharp\.git\";
```

and got another exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: LibGit2Sharp.LibGit2SharpException: An error was raised by libgit2. Category = Config (Error).
Failed to parse config file: Unexpected end of file while parsing multine var (in c:/work/ConsoleApplication1/bin/Debug/targetDir/config:23, column 0)
   at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Ensure.Success(Int32 result, Boolean allowPositiveResult) in c:\work\libgit2sharp\LibGit2Sharp\Core\Ensure.cs:line 85
   at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Proxy.git_clone_bare(String url, String workdir, git_transfer_progress_callback transfer_cb) in c:\work\libgit2sharp\LibGit2Sharp\Core\Proxy.cs:line 219
   at LibGit2Sharp.Repository.Clone(String sourceUrl, String workdirPath, Boolean bare, Boolean checkout, TransferProgressHandler onTransferProgress, CheckoutProgressHandler onCheckoutProgress) in c:\work\libgit2sharp\LibGit2Sharp\Repository.cs:line 431
   at Program.Main() in c:\work\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line 12
```

`targetDir` is never created.

If on the other hand I use HTTP transport, the `Repository.Clone` method works fine:

```
var sourceUrl = "https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp";
```

So my question is if I am doing something wrong or if this is unsupported feature or a bug in the native `git2.dll`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So my question is if I am doing something wrong or if this is unsupported feature or a bug in the native git2.dll?

A bit a both, actually.

- The first exception is clearly a bug. This **should not** happen and will be troubleshot.
- The second one requires a deeper analysis. Would you be so kind as to open a issue in the LibGit2Sharp project?

Good news are that a pull request from **[BenStraub](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1319/ben-straub)** was recently merged. This **[pull request](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/1049)** implements the local fetch transport which should pretty solve the issue.

LibGit2Sharp will be updated in the following days with a new a new version of libgit2 binaries which should allow you perform a local clone/fetch. I'll update this answer as soon as it's been done.

### Update

This **[test](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/CloneFixture.cs#L53-L90)** shows how do to a Clone and a Push over against a local repository.

Comment: Thanks, issue opened: https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/247. Looking forward to the new version of libgit2.